# create AssetBundleBuild with more files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets, assetbundle

I wish create an assetbundle that contains some text files that are textassets into my project..

the strange thing is if I do this:

```
AssetBundleBuild buildInfo = new AssetBundleBuild { 
    assetBundleName = "textAssets.unity3d",
    assetNames = new [] {"Assets/firstFile.txt"}};
}
```

it works and create an textAssets.unity3d with the file inside, but if I do this:

```
AssetBundleBuild buildInfo = new AssetBundleBuild { 
    assetBundleName = "textAssets.unity3d",
    assetNames = new [] {"Assets/firstFile.txt", "Assets/secondFile.txt"}};
}
```

it doesn't work, seems that I need to create a assetbundle for each prefab/file.txt
thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't create the `textAssets.unity3d` file? Stupid question: Are you sure that both files exist where you've said they exist? Is any exception thrown?

Comment: both files exists, no exception (if I duplicate the first code, I obtain the right 2 unity3d files)

Comment: Try `new string[] {}` maybe...not sure why that would be a problem, but maybe? I'm out of ideas otherwise. Documentation seems to indicate this should work.